# Save an image and other data to a file in delphi

Tags: delphi

I have an image, a string, and an integer that i need to save/read as a file. What would be the best way to do this. I was thinking a TStream, but I am unsure of how to implement it.

Comment: This is very, very broad. There are many ways to save info to a file. But **best** depends on many things. Who will be reading the file? What version of Delphi are you using? What encoding is needed for that string value? Will this be saved and loaded across platforms? You really must provide much more details if you want a good answer.

Comment: Delphi XE3. Basically I want to save to a file an Image that has a caption and value attached to it. When loading the file it should be able to read the image data, the caption, and the value attached to the image and display it in the relevant controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Delphi's built-in component streaming support and save it either as binary or text data. One disadvantage with this method is if your images are high-resolution then you might be punished in greater file-size when dumping the in-memory-pixel-data to disk compared to the image's original file-format, e.g. jpeg. In my example below I derive a class from `TImage` and add a string value, `MyString` and an integer, `MyInteger` and save as binary data.

**Stream Component to/from a binary-file**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TMyImage = class(TImage)
  private
    FString : string;
    FInteger : integer;
  public

  published
    property MyString: string read FString write FString;
    property MyInteger: Integer read FInteger write FInteger;
  end;

  TFormMain = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FMyImage : TMyImage;
    FMyImage2 : TMyImage;
  public

  end;

var
  FormMain: TFormMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}    

procedure WriteComponent(Component: TComponent; Filename : String);
var
  m :TMemoryStream;    
begin
  m := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    m.WriteComponent(Component);
    m.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
    m.SaveToFile(Filename);
  finally
    m.Free;
  end;
end;

function ReadComponent(Filename : String): TComponent;
var
  m :TMemoryStream;    
begin
  m := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    m.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    m.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
    result := m.ReadComponent(nil);
  finally
    m.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TFormMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FMyImage := TMyImage.Create(Self);

  FMyImage.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\...\Delphi\Common Images\ALIGNPAL.BMP');
  FMyImage.MyString := 'Hello World';
  FMyImage.MyInteger := 12345;

  WriteComponent(FMyImage, 'c:\test.dat');
  FMyImage2 := ReadComponent('c:\test.dat') as TMyImage;
end;

initialization

 RegisterClass(TMyImage);

end.
```

**A simplified approach**

If you want to get by with only one String and one Integer than you could use TImage's Caption and Tag properties.

```
...
FImage : TImage;
FImage2 : TImage;
....

procedure TFormMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FImage := TImage.Create(Self);

  FImage.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\...\Delphi\Common Images\ALIGNPAL.BMP');
  FImage.Caption := 'Hello World';
  FImage.Tag := 12345;

  WriteComponent(FImage, 'c:\test.dat');

  FImage2 := ReadComponent('c:\test.dat') as TImage;
end;
```

**Stream Component to/from text**

Below I'v also added useful helper functions, [found here](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TStream_WriteComponent.html), if you want more "readable" data-files by making string representations of the binary-data. File size will however increase.

```
function StringToComponentProc(Value: string): TComponent;
var
  StrStream:TStringStream;
  BinStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  StrStream := TStringStream.Create(Value);
  try
    BinStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      ObjectTextToBinary(StrStream, BinStream);
      BinStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      Result:= BinStream.ReadComponent(nil);
    finally
      BinStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    StrStream.Free;
  end;
end;

function ComponentToStringProc(Component: TComponent): string;
var
  BinStream:TMemoryStream;
  StrStream: TStringStream;
  s: string;
begin
  BinStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    StrStream := TStringStream.Create(s);
    try
      BinStream.WriteComponent(Component);
      BinStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      ObjectBinaryToText(BinStream, StrStream);
      StrStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      Result:= StrStream.DataString;
    finally
      StrStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    BinStream.Free
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Used your code and within an hour wrote a utility to do what I wanted to achieve. Brilliant. The Lacuna Expanse Glyph Recipe Cookbook is now migrated from failure to success.

Comment: To my mind the problem with this is you have a rather non standard persistence format. What happens when Emba change the format in a future release. Or if somebody else wants to read your file that isn't using Delphi. That's why I'd advocate standard formats.

Answer (score 4):

Whilst you could roll your own container format, it would make more sense to me to use a pre-existing one.

The most obvious choice to me is a ZIP file. Delphi has built in libraries to read and write ZIP files. This is how Office saves its files. Just as Office does, you do not need to use a .zip extension.

You could put the image in one file in the ZIP, and the metadata in another. The metadata could be persisted as JSON, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Some interesting approches to **adding arbitrary data to an image without affecting usability** are discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385415/adding-arbitrary-data-to-an-image-without-affecting-usability) SO question.

- **Exif** - Exchangeable image file format is a standard that specifies the formats for images, sound, and ancillary tags used by digital cameras (including smartphones), scanners and other systems handling image and sound files recorded by digital cameras.
- **XMP** - The Extensible Metadata Platform is an ISO standard, originally created by Adobe Systems Inc., for the creation, processing and interchange of standardized and custom metadata for all kinds of resources.
- **Steganography** is the art or practice of concealing a message, image, or file within another message, image, or file.